# Generic parent of generic child C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics

I've got a parent class Container that may contain any kind of Node, where Node is a subclass of a generic class specific to the parent, like so:

```
public class ContainerBase<NodeType, ObjectType>
    where NodeType : NodeBase<ObjectType> where ObjectType : ObjectBase {
}

public abstract class NodeBase<T> where T : ObjectBase {
    ContainerBase<NodeBase<T>, T> container;
    public NodeBase(ContainerBase<NodeBase<T>, T> owner) {
        container = owner;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is create concrete subclasses for simplicity that implement standard object types:

```
public class ContainerNormal : ContainerBase<NodeNormal, ObjectNormal> {
}

public class NodeNormal : NodeBase<ObjectNormal> {
    //This doesn't work
    public NodeNormal(ContainerNormal owner) : base(owner) { }
}
```

I somewhat understand why the call to the base constructor doesn't work.  It's trying to convert a `ContainerNormal` to a `ContainerBase<NodeBase<ObjectNormal>, ObjectNormal>` which doesn't really work.

So what design pattern am I missing to make this work right?  Or do I just have to take in a `ContainerBase<NodeBase<ObjectNormal>,ObjectNormal>` in the constructor, even though it may not necessarily be a `ContainerNormal` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explore: [Covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29), but this should work:

```
public class Container<TNode, T> where TNode : Node<T> { }

public abstract class Node<T>
{
    Container<Node<T>, T> container;

    public Node(Container<Node<T>, T> owner)
    {
        this.container = owner;
    }
}

public class ContainerNormal<T> : Container<Node<T>, T> { }

public class NodeNormal<T> : Node<T>
{
    public NodeNormal(ContainerNormal<T> container)
        : base(container)
    {
    }
}

public class ContainerNormal : ContainerNormal<string> { }

public class NodeNormal : NodeNormal<string>
{
    public NodeNormal(ContainerNormal container)
        : base(container)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it may actually work, although it will end up cluttering the namespace a bit...

Comment: After inspection, it seems to have the same problem as Can Gencer's answer, in that trying to get a NodeNormal from a ContainerNormal will instead return a Node<String>, which is almost the same, but not quite.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 4 you can accomplish this using generic interface covariance:

```
public class ContainerBase<NodeType, ObjectType> : IContainerBase<NodeType, ObjectType>
    where NodeType : NodeBase<ObjectType> where ObjectType : ObjectBase {
}

public abstract class NodeBase<T> where T : ObjectBase {
    IContainerBase<NodeBase<T>, T> container;
    public NodeBase(IContainerBase<NodeBase<T>, T> owner) {
        container = owner;
    }
}

public class ContainerNormal : ContainerBase<NodeNormal, ObjectNormal> {
}

public interface IContainerBase<out NodeType, ObjectType>
    where NodeType : NodeBase<ObjectType> where ObjectType : ObjectBase {
}

public class NodeNormal : NodeBase<ObjectNormal> {
    //This doesn't work
    public NodeNormal(ContainerNormal owner) : base(owner) { }
}

public class ObjectNormal : ObjectBase {}

public class ObjectBase{}
```

Of course, this will only work if your IContainerBase interface can avoid having any functions that would take a `NodeType` as input. For example, this would work:

```
public interface IContainerBase<out NodeType, ObjectType>
    where NodeType : NodeBase<ObjectType> where ObjectType : ObjectBase 
{
    NodeType NodeTypeProp {get;}
}
```

... but this wouldn't:

```
public interface IContainerBase<out NodeType, ObjectType>
    where NodeType : NodeBase<ObjectType> where ObjectType : ObjectBase 
{
    NodeType NodeTypeProp {get;set;} // "set" not allowed on "out" type
}
```

One more note: You notice how I had to name the property "NodeTypeProp" instead of "NodeType"? That's because we're not following C# naming conventions. You should prefix generic type names with "T":

```
public interface IContainerBase<out TNodeType, TObjectType>
    where TNodeType : NodeBase<TObjectType> where TObjectType : ObjectBase
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck on .NET 3.5, otherwise this sounds like the cleanest solution.

Comment: @Ed Marty: That's a shame. What I've had to do in the past for things like this is tightly couple all of these classes together. So NodeBase's generic arguments would include the ContainerBase type and ContainerBase's generic arguments would include the NodeBase type. It's ugly.

Answer (score 1):

There is one trick you can you that I think would get what you want.  You could give NodeBase an additional generic parameter that must inherit from NodeBase.  This is gives a type definition that appears recursive, but the compiler has a way it works it out.  Something like this should work:

```
public class NodeBase<T, TNode> :
    where T : ObjectBase
    where TNode : NodeBase<T, TNode>
{ 
    private ContainerBase<TNode, T> container;

    protected NodeBase(ContainerBase<TNode, T> owner)
    {  container = owner; }
}

public class ContainerBase<NodeType, ObjectType> :
    where NodeType : NodeBase<ObjectType, NodeType>
    where ObjectType : ObjectBase
{
    public NodeType GetItem() { ... }
}

public class NodeNormal : NodeBase<ObjectNormal, NodeNormal>
{
    public NodeNormal(ContainerNormal owner) :
        base(owner) { }
}

public class ContainerNormal : 
    ContainerBase<NodeNormal, ObjectNormal>
{ 
    //GetItem would return NodeNormal here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can can change the definition of Container normal as follows:

```
public class ContainerNormal : ContainerBase<NodeBase<ObjectNormal>, ObjectNormal>
{
}
```

Comment: That would fix the compile error, but it doesn't solve the problem that, for example, children other than NodeNormals can be stored in ContainerNormals.  And if I try to get a child out of a ContainerNormal, it will be of type NodeBase<ObjectNormal> instead of NodeNormal.  So if I wanted to add any methods to NodeNormal and call them on an object I got out of a ContainerNormal, it wouldn't work without casting.

Comment: Yes in that case you would need the intermediate class which inherits from ContainerBase<NodeBase<ObjectNormal>, ObjectNormal> such as a ContainerNormal<ObjectType> : ContainerBase<NodeBase<ObjectType>, ObjectType>. I think it will get messy and suddenly you will have two types of ContainerNormals to deal with. You can add a property to ContainerNormal to get the ObjectNormal directly, and add a method to validate that it always gets ObjectNormals. A bit messy but I think it will be easier to use API wise.

Comment: It should be a non-issue if you don't plan on implementing more than one type which will inherit from NodeBase<ObjectNormal>.

Comment: Except I am planning on doing such, and even if I weren't I still need to cast to the correct type.